# Remove bracket of a array python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

In here, i want to ask how to remove bracket of a array in python. This is my following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0, header=0)
X = np.array(df.ix[:,0:29])
Y = np.array(df.ix[:,29:30])
Y
Out[55]:
array([[ 1],
       [ 2],
       [ 3],
       ..., 
       [35],
       [36],
       [37]], dtype=int64)
```

The desired output is following below:

```
Y
Out[55]:
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,....])
```

I already tried to use `np.array`, however it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if it works

```
X = np.array(df.ix[:,0:29])
Y = np.array(df.ix[:,29:30])
Y = Y[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Y = df.ix[:,29:30].values.ravel()
```

`df` is a dataframe; `df.ix[:,29:30]` a slice; `df.ix[].values` the values as a numpy array.  Use `.ravel()` (or `.flatten()`) to convert it from 2d to 1d as needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
Y = np.array(df.ix[:,29:30])
Y.shape = (len(Y))
Y
```